# Multiple objects following multiple paths in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to perform a simple animation using Animation Nodes. I have some objects in scene and some path I want them to follow.

So questions I stuck into are:

1. How can I get a spline list from collection of objects?
2. How to assign an exact path to every object? When I try to match lists, node "Get List Element" appears. I assume I should use a loop but can't get what to iterate[image]

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

you can easily create the spline list like this:

[image]

press on "x"  then you get:

[image]

In the outliner select your splines...

[image]

then tap "from selection"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

That helps. Just one more tip for those who faces the same issues.
Nurbs curves with less than 6 points don't work, one have to convert them to Bezier curves. I added more control points to make it possible.

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the checkmark left to my answer if my answer helped you. Thanks.